# What is or inside int in python?

Tags: python

This function:

```
def posts(request):

    # Get start and end points
    start = int(request.GET.get("start") or 0)
    end = int(request.GET.get("end") or (start + 9))

    # Generate list of posts
    data = []
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        data.append(f"Post #{i}")

    # Artificially delay speed of response
    time.sleep(1)

    # Return list of posts
    return JsonResponse({
        "posts": data
    })
```

in view.py, what is `or` in these two lines?

```
start = int(request.GET.get("start") or 0)
end = int(request.GET.get("end") or (start + 9))
```

Comment: Read the duplicates to understand how `or` is used as a conditional assignment operator, but in your case it is not necessary as you can pass a default value to `.get()` (i.e. `start = int(request.GET.get("start", 0))`).

Comment: The definition of `x or y` in Python is `x if x is true, otherwise y`.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Thank you for this answer simplicity.